# Converter to use Sata HDD with IBM eserver x236

Tags: hardware, storage, hard-drive, ibm, ibm-xseries

We have an old x236 machine with 2 70-GB SCSI disks installed on Ultra320 SCSI connector ([check out the hardware manual](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/systems/support/system_x_pdf/25k8114.pdf)). Now, we are planning to buy a new server in future and x326 would act as a backup machine (no more resource hungry processing). So, we need to use cheap 2TB SATA HDD. When I opened the server myself, couple of queries came into my mind:

1. Since there are variety of SATA-to-SCSI controllers (like
   [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WBMU1E)), would it work with x236 machine without reconfiguring
   RAID?
2. Would that converter (in the aforementioned link) works with all kind of SCSI interfaces, especially the one in x326 (29pins or 80pins? this is confusing!)?
3. As the converter has multiple SATA cables, does that means it can map many sata HDDs on one SCSI slot?

Please cure my curiosity! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SCSI-to-SATA connector, but SAS-to-SATA, which is a big difference! You cannot plug SATA drive to SCSI hostadapter. On the Amazon link you ment is SFF-8484 connector, which you cannot plug even to 80-pin or 29-pin SCSI hostadapter.
SAS is a serial-attached-SCSI, but normal SCSI have a parallel bus. You have to have a converter like [this](http://www.pc-pitstop.com/scsi_ide_adapters/aec7730a.asp), but in my point of view, this is risky in the enterprise environment.